# Rails: Adding new column to certain entries of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make an online marketplace Rails App and I wanted to add a new column to my database conditional on another column.

I have a rails model "listings", which contains fields: "name, price, description, category." There are several categories: e.g., "Apartments, Books, Electronics,..." I want to add "Lat" and "Lon" geolocation columns **only** for Apartment listings. Would this be possible? How would I go about it?

*I'm new to Ruby, so I apologize if this is a really easy question.*

Thanks!

Comment: try geokit or geocoder gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a model is a table, all the records will have the same attributes.

You can let them nil for other categories than apartments (and keep only one model), or you can create an herited model Apartments from Listings (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Saraf answer nails it pretty much. Well, this is the case that you consider you have a SQL database. If you want to use a NoSQL database, such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), you can store whatever you want inside collections (think about it as storing JSON objects).

Edit: clarification

1. You use **SQL DB** and you need to think about your relational schema and how you will handle different data (inheritance, for instance).
2. You use **NoSQL DB** and you can store "JSON objects" freely in your collections.